# Is it possible to launch an app with an item in the lazyRow clicked in jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

Can I launch my app with the last index of my lazyRow clicked? I have a list of dates that I wanted the informations of the last date to be launched with the app

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I get your question, but you can use `LaunchEffect` to run some code when your composable is first displayed. So, the only thing you need to do is get the item from the list and do whatever you want...

```
@Composable
fun YourComposable() {
    val yourList = listOf("A", "B", "C")
    LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
        if (someList.isNotEmpty()) {
            val lastItem = yourList.last()
            // do what you want with the item...
        }
    }
}
```